# lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit

Tags: boot, lubuntu, lvm

After install Lubuntu 16.04 show the following message during the boot:

```
lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: clean, 121574/7168000 files, 1115621/2865544 blocks
```

I wait 1 hour but don't show the login screen.

I can login using <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, return "Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" in a screen like terminal... but I dont know how continue to can use the computer or fix the problem... Some suggestion?

Comment: there was a graphic problem.  Hold 'right shift' key during boot to access the Grub then press 'e' key to edit  commands. Locate the words 'quiet splash' on screen, then use arrow keys to navigate and add the word 'nomodeset' just after 'quiet splash'(leave a space before and after 'nomodeset'). Press 'F10' key after typing 'nomodeset' to boot the system.  Then use Synaptic to install the drivers 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' and 'xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg', restarted and all works perfectly now. I found this solution in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2321734&p=13482015#post13482015

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this for my machines by adjusting the grub configuration like so:

In `/etc/default/grub`, change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to 
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Then add this line:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
```

Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: ruined my ubuntu

Comment: fixed my ubuntu server

Comment: This is a horrible answer. Do not apply it since: first, is unrelated to the issue and second may create additional problems.