# "Lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysini" message receive before entering my bios passphrase

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-repair, passphrase

I am new to linux and Ubuntu, I cannot seem to login to my system.  I noticed this before I enter the passphrase, I receive the error messages:

Lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit

Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found

Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg

There was a question about this earlier, but the solution to it went way over my head.

["Lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit" on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/797128/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet-using-direct-activation-during-sysinit-on-boot/797285)

Question, if I use boot repair will it resolve this issue without affecting any of my data?  I check my memory and my cpu and they seem to be working fine.

Thanks.