# Failure of ubuntu 16.04 clean installs

Tags: boot, 16.04

I have two machines one has been running ubuntu for a while and the other was a windows machine both were updated to ubuntu 16.04 by a clean install about 3-4 weeks ago and both worked well. Today both machines have failed with similar messages Ivmetad is not active, no cache page mode found assuming drive cache writethrough, recovering journal and then clean files blocks. same messages appear when I try to load an earlier kernel. Im not clear how long the clean process will take so I have left the machine although it has advanced the cursor to the next line

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `/etc/default/grub` file.  Replace your `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option from `quiet splash" with`nomodeset`

Change from:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change to:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
```

Also add this line to your grub configuration:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
```

It should look like:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=15
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console serial"
```

Then update your grub with:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot.

This is taken from:

[Lvmetad is not active yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767140/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet)
[lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769863/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet-using-direct-activation-during-sysinit)