# lvmetad is blocking boot process

Tags: boot, lvm

I have a problem during boot: I see the message `lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit`. The message completely blocks my login process. I'm not able to switch to a non-graphical login screen (they all just show a blinking cursor) or perform any other action than rebooting with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>DEL</kbd>.

If I wait for a very long time (more than 10 minutes) I get the following message:

```
resume: Could not stat the resume file /dev/disk/by-uuid/a62a5e02...
Please type in the full path name to try again or press ENTER to boot the system:
```

If I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, booting resumes and my login screen comes up within a second - this only seems to work with older kernels <=4.4.0-43, with newer kernels, ENTER does nothing and I also cannot enter anything else using the keyboard.

The message after the 10 minute break `resume: ...` led me to think it could be related to a stale disk image after suspending to RAM, but I have no idea how to fix this.

I see no errors in `dmesg`, everything related to LVM looks fine there.

For a while I was able to boot without delay using kernel 4.4.0-43, but today (after a apt-get kernel upgrade) even this stopped to work.

I found these two threads about the problem, but I'm reluctant to try to change the grub video settings, since they (should) have nothing to do with `lvmetad` and users report that this workaround came with its own set of issues.

[Lvmetad is not active yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767140/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet)

[lvmetad is not active yet; using direct activation during sysinit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769863/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet-using-direct-activation-during-sysinit)

Can anybody talk me through this? Even in the old days booting did not take 10 minutes and nowadays it a 10 minute timeout seems to be a bit over the top... ;)

[EDIT] **Here is the requested output:**

blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="2EC7-7121" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="77533e31-4b1a-40da-9e49-ecebfb701229"
/dev/sda2: UUID="b206ab4e-2119-4d90-ab77-5088177faa08" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="a5ddb725-1822-4847-8fd3-c1566b83f740"
/dev/sda3: UUID="uhcPym-YPqH-XGTC-Y0YB-ynxd-K4iK-b0viGE" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="455fe5cf-64a0-4ef5-b3e7-19e5f86b3ee4"
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: UUID="cba585cc-e15b-419c-b055-f1fe2a56c7da" TYPE="ext4"
```

cat /etc/fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=b206ab4e-2119-4d90-ab77-5088177faa08 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=2EC7-7121  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

swapon did not produce any output, but with option -a:

```
swapon: stat of /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 failed: No such file or directory
```

**[EDIT]** In my grub.cfg I find references to an lvmid that does not correspond to any of the blkid - can this be the issue?

```
set root='lvmid/nvk03P-ihq7-kTsM-LvZ4-DzQu-iOag-4BOz7I/kHYiDJ-9NSq-Wlkc-0YXH-HiX2-SVZ7-MPSFnp'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/nvk03P-ihq7-kTsM-LvZ4-DzQu-iOag-4BOz7I/kHYiDJ-9NSq-Wlkc-0YXH-HiX2-SVZ7-MPSFnp'  cba585    cc-e15b-419c-b055-f1fe2a56c7da
```

Also in grub.cfg there are some references to root and UUIDs - the UUID correspond to /boot (sda2) with `--set root b2...` and but two lines below there is `root=/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root` which is a different device:

```
[---snip---]
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  b206ab4e-2119-4d90-ab77-5088177faa08
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root b206ab4e-2119-4d90-ab77-5088177faa08
    fi
    linux   /vmlinuz-4.4.0-57-generic.efi.signed root=/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
[---snip---]
```

**[EDIT]**
Commenting the swap line in fstab does not help with booting and once the system boots, lvdisplay shows both, the root and the swap partition:

```
lvm> lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/kubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                kubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                kHYiDJ-9NSq-Wlkc-0YXH-HiX2-SVZ7-MPSFnp
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time kubuntu, 2016-06-07 12:33:08 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                432.86 GiB
  Current LE             110811
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/kubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                kubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                YiuKj2-FVgn-ufGg-lvZ5-IML5-w3hH-ZeHrrH
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time kubuntu, 2016-06-07 12:33:08 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV     Size                31.93 GiB
  Current LE             8173
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

**[EDIT]**
Following the suggestions of heynnema below, I remove and re-added swap. There was indeed something wrong : /proc/swaps was empty and free showed a total of 0 before removing and re-creating swap. Now it gets mounted properly and free as well as /proc/swaps show the expected output. Unfortunately the initial issue with the boot delay persists. **After this step, I had to update iniramfs (`update-initramfs -k all -c`) - now it works. Phew. Thanks to heynnema for the great support!**

Comment: It sounds like its not finding your swap disk. Did you make changes in your disk partitions? From GRUB, enter Recovery mode, root access, and show us the output of `blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: ps: and the `swapon` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit` is a normal message, and is not causing your boot problem.

#### Somebody deleted your swap partition.

`/etc/fstab` has this line:

```
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

looking for a swap partition it never finds. The `sudo blkid` and the `swapon` commands confirm this.

#### Short term fix, comment out the above line in `fstab`:

In terminal...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

change

```
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

to this

```
#/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

This will allow you to boot in a normal timeframe, but the system will have no defined swap space.

#### Long term fix, install the LVM GUI tool to manage your LVM disks:

In terminal...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

Go to the Unity dashboard and type `lvm`. Use this GUI tool to remake your LVM swap partition. Then go back and uncomment the line from the short term fix.

Comment: The short term fix (commenting swap in fstab) did not change anything. As for the long-term fix: lvdisplay does show a swap partition. I'll add the full information in the original question.

Comment: Is your `sudo blkid` missing a line for `/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1`? What does a `pvdisplay` show?

Comment: Maybe do a `swapoff` (probably not really required) then remake your swap lv by deleting and re-adding it, uncommenting fstab, then do a `swapon -a`?

Comment: blkid _does_ show the swap now (`/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="a62a5e02-61c5-4061-8133-3accc4815743" TYPE="swap"
`), it did not when I called it from the failsafe mode.

Comment: That's the same UUID called out in the error "Could not stat the resume file /dev/disk/by-uuid/a62a5e02...". I can't see the full UUID to compare. You might look at `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` and see if the UUID matches. Somewhere the UUIDs probably don't match. Or, as I suggested, you just need to remake your swap.

Comment: ps: or maybe `sudo update-initramfs -c`

Comment: What finally fixed it?

Comment: removing (`lvremove`) and adding (`lvcreate`, `mkswap`) swap, then updating initram (`update-initramfs -k all -c`)

Comment: Remember to update /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume with the correct new UUID.

Comment: Thanks @heynnema! All done! Let me know if I can buy you a beer or something!

Comment: You're welcome. Just "pay it forward" to somebody else who needs help.