# lvmetad not active ubuntu--vg-root clean NO BOOT due to AMDGPU-PRO

Tags: boot, 16.04, xorg, lvm, amdgpu

I cannot boot ubuntu correctly since last kernel update.
`uname -r` gives 4.4.0-83-generic

After booting, I get following message:

```
lvmetad is not active yet, using direct activation during sysinit
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 1014488/15097856 files, 29730400/60376064 blocks
```

Basycally, I have the very same error than [Lvmetad is not active yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767140/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet/886865#886865) except no login screen is shown: **it freezes here**. Waiting very long doesn't change anything.

I tried the following solutions by using tty2:

- `uselvmetad = 0` change in `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` ==> no change
- [lvmetad is blocking boot process](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865869/lvmetad-is-blocking-boot-process?rq=1) except when I wait very long, nothing happen. My `/proc/swaps` file was empty like OP. After doing his solution, here's the cat of it:
  `/dev/dm-1 partition 8302588 0 -1` ==> still no booting. Note that `update-initramfs -k all -c` worked properly for the last 3 installed kernels, bugged for the previous ones (that I removed with `apt-get autoremove` not sure why they appear but this seems unrelated to my issue)
- I enabled and started the lvm2-lvmetad.service and .socket such as explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/199164/error-run-lvm-lvmetad-socket-connect-failed-no-such-file-or-directory-but .
- I did try some of the solution from a live ubuntu USB stick
- I did try some of the solution from recovery-mode: at some points it crashes and I have no time to read the error messages
- I did try to return to previous kernells: samely unabootable.

I cannot copy and paste, but I can say that:

```
>> sudo lvdisplay
```

`/dev/ubuntu-vg/root` & `/dev/ubuntu-vg/swap_1` appear correctly

```
>> sudo blkid
```

`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root` with ext4 and `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1` with swap type appear correctly and UUID of the latter corresponds under `cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

```
 >>cat /etc/fstab
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
 UUID=XXX /boot ext2 defaults 0 2#the correct UUID appears here, just too long to copy
 #/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none swap swap 0 0#this was commented out manually
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 swap swap defaults 0 0#this was added manually
```

I tried alternatively to use /dev/ubuntu-vg/root and ./swap as well as use the UUIDs instead: no change.

I believe the problem comes from displaying, so here is a sample of lspci

```
  >>lspci -v
  XXX [AMD/ATI] Tonga PRO [Radeon R9 285/380] (rev f1)
  Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
  Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Down-voting because already asked on the forum? Please be constructive and comment with the link to the solution I did not already try. thank you.

**EDIT:**
I tried to update my grub, but I had a lot of errors due to disabled lvmetad. I rechanged lvmetad to 1, then did update grub with no problem.
Now when I reboot, only the second line appears, not the first, e.g.:

```
 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 1014488/15097856 files, 29730400/60376064 blocks
```

I guess it's normal as now lvmetad is reactivated.

**EDIT2:**
It seems I do have a problem with either amdgpu-pro or xorg. I cannot display correctly, even with live-USB (forgot to mention that). Readding tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is really due to AMDGPU-PRO. My previous version was 16.30. It seems it doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS anymore, you need to go to 17.10

Solution:

- go to http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx from another computer
- Download on the other computer the driver (version 17.10)
- you can unpack it as explained on the amd website
- copy to a usb stick
- start in normal mode your faulty computer, go to tty (ctrl + alt + F1)
- mount the usb stick (note your usb might be elsewhere than on /dev/dbb1)

  ```
  mkdir /media/usb
  mount /dev/dbb1 /media/usb
  cp media/usb/amdgpu....tar.xz /tmp
  ```
- after copying to /tmp, first uninstall the previous version `amdgpu-pro-uninstall`
- then follow amd's website install procedure as usual.
- after rebooting, I had problems with login in. you need to check who owns .Xauthority: `ls -lA`. If it is root:root instead of your username, then do `sudo chown username:username .Xauthority` (with `username` being your real username ;) )

I still have weird issues around, but at least I can use my computer correctly.