# Unable to boot ubuntu16.04

Tags: 16.04

[image: picture]
    `Getting lvmetad is not active yet , using direct activation during sysinit`

```
/dev/mapper/dhcp--10--47--100--93-vg-root:clean
```

We are able to boot through bootable USB.

@David Foerster Actually this is server pc , I don't know what has gone wrong .Any solution to recover other than reinstalling.

Comment: May be the duplicate of this question. Refer the link: 
[Lvmetad is not active yet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/767140/lvmetad-is-not-active-yet)

Comment: tried changing use_lvmetad = 0 , still same error .

Comment: What’s your question? What did you do to get to the current situation? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep running into errors, [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), has solved quite a few of these issues for me. Might not be the fix but is worth a chance in my opinion. If you're unfamiliar, from your live USB:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Comment: try this after booting through bootable usb ?

Comment: Indeed, sorry updated the answer.

Comment: unable to connect to network .. :(

Comment: I forgot to mention, you'll need an internet connection to do this. If you're able to, plug an ethernet in for ease. If not, you'll have to use the applet on the top bar, or search for a program containing the word wifi/net (I cannot remember which program it is).

Comment: connected Ethernet , unable to connect to internet

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure why the internet isn't working. Perhaps someone else has an idea?

Comment: is it possible i can download boot-repair from other place and copy it in usb and install here ?

Comment: @AmruthA You can download [Boot-Repair-Disk](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) and use it instead of the Ubuntu live USB in this procedure.